# Two Drop Down options with a button

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to get this work.

I have 2 dropdown lists. Once the user select the required value and click the button. The button will load specific URL based on the selected options in both the dropdowns.

https://jsfiddle.net/vs3q879c/

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

        OR = document.getElementById("orientation");
        SZ = document.getElementById("size");
        ORSZ = OR + SZ;




        switch (ORSZ) {
          case PA5:
            window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/one.html";
            break;

          case PA4:
            window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/two.html";
            break;

          case PA3:
            window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/three.html";
            break;

          case LA5:
            window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/four.html";
            break;

          case LA4:
            window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/five.html";
            break;

          case LA3:
            window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/six.html";
            break;

          default:
          default none();
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Hey you have to check get the value of the particular selected option please see you can do something like this   var value = OR.options[OR.selectedIndex].value;
var text = OR.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

Answer (score 1):

You have a few mistakes. Instead of using `window.location.href`, try using `window.open("www.my-url.com")`.

Also, you have 2 default statements in your `switch clause`, try something like this:

```
switch (ORSZ) {
    case PA5:
        window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/one.html";
        break;

    case PA4:
        window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/two.html";
        break;

    case PA3:
        window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/three.html";
        break;

    case LA5:
        window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/four.html";
        break;

    case LA4:
        window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/five.html";
        break;

    case LA3:
        window.location.href = "www.xxxx.wwww/six.html";
        break;

    default: none();
}
```

Lastly, when you're getting the select elements by ID, you're grabbing the object instead of the selected value. To fix that, you need to use `.value`:

```
OR = document.getElementById("orientation").value;
SZ = document.getElementById("size").value;
ORSZ = OR + SZ;
```

***DEMO: http://jsbin.com/tivocodeza/edit?html,js,output***

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the above - grab the value of the input, not the element.

You are also using jQuery in your fiddle `$(document).ready();`

if you are doing that, you can use jQuery for everything. Not sure you want that but in case you do, here is a code suggestion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ORSZ = $('#orientation').val() + $('size').val();

    switch (ORSZ) {
      case PA5:
      window.open("www.xxxx.wwww/one.html", '_blank');
    break;

    //e
    //t
    //c

  });
});
```

I added the `id="submit"` to your button to make it easier to select.